# Deploy Typescript project for use in browser?

Tags: typescript

I've created a small project using Typescript that I wish to publish as a Node package. Since it gets compiled into JS, my hope is that both Typescript and Javascript coders can implement my project.

However, I'm not sure how to test the application in-browser, since I can't use `require` (`Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`).

How can I test my application locally, but also set it up deploy it, so that someone could either use `import * as myProject from 'myproject` or `var myProject = require('myproject')`?

Comment: Typically people will use *another* build tool to turn your source into something that's easier for the browser to digest. Popular ones are Webpack, Rollup and Browserify.

Comment: What does "deploy it" mean on browser. You want to use `require` but not in bundled code?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to check your library before publishing:

**First solution**

```
npm install /absolute/path/to/your-lib
```

And that yields this in our package.json file:

```
"dependencies": {
  "your-lib": "file:../../path/your-lib",
}
```

**Second solution**

```
~/path/to/your-lib $ npm link
~/path/to/some-lib $ npm link package-name
```

Information about this solution in official npm site: [NPM Link](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link)